# communication with real SIM cards in a standard USB PCSC reader

Tags: android, smartcard

I want to connect a javacard in a usb cardreader that is connected pc via android emulator. I fonund I can do it with seek and saw [enter link description here](http://simhacks.github.io/android-emulator/)

or [enter link description here](https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool/wiki/EmulatorExtension) but I don't know :
1- How to get 
    - Android 4.2.2 (API 17) / Simhacks x86 System Image 
    -  Extras / Simhacks Emulator 
in this article [enter link description here](http://simhacks.github.io/android-emulator/) not exist any address.

2- How to start the patched emulator?I'm beginner in android and I don't know how is it patched. I got smartcard-api-4_0_0.tar and Unzip it. but I don't know where is android src? I use eclipse and windows 7 but this step are not for windows .

Answer (score 0):

I've built [this repository](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/pcsc-android-emulator) where you can download an x86 emulator built with [seek-for-android](https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool) pcsc patch if you don't want to build AOSP.

It also contains complementary/additionnal instructions in case you want to build it yourself.

Supposing you have created an AVD with system image sdk21 x86 named "smartcard" :

```
mkdir pcsc-emulator && cd pcsc-emulator
wget https://github.com/bertrandmartel/pcsc-android-emulator/releases/download/v1.0/emulator.tar.gz
tar -xvzf emulator.tar.gz && rm emulator.tar.gz
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Android/Sdk #change this
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/pcsc-lite:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./emulator/emulator @smartcard -verbose -system system.img -pcsc
```

Note that the reader must be plugged in when you launch the emulator.